# Cannot understand the details of using shared memory

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, mapping, shared-memory

I am new to C++ and I don't understand what is happening in this piece of program:

```
    class FasterRCNN {
private:
    int m_base_model;
    std::string m_key_mutex = "";
    HANDLE  m_mutex = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    std::string m_key_shmem = "";
    HANDLE  m_shmem = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    DWORD m_size = 0;
    char* m_buffer = nullptr;
    std::vector<std::string> m_class_map;
public:
    void Create(int base_model, std::string model_path, std::string classfile, DWORD size = 10000, float filter_threshold = 0.4F) {
        m_base_model = base_model;
        m_key_shmem = this->GetKey() + "_shmem";
        m_key_mutex = this->GetKey() + "_mutex";
        m_size = size;

        m_mutex = ::CreateMutexA(nullptr, FALSE, m_key_mutex.c_str());
        m_shmem = ::CreateFileMappingA(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, nullptr, PAGE_READWRITE, 0, m_size, m_key_shmem.c_str());
        m_buffer = (char*)::MapViewOfFile(m_shmem, FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, 0, 0, m_size);
        m_buffer[0] = 0;
```

I can't understand how **m_buffer** gets it's values in last lines.
I know that:

- **GetKey** is for getting millisecond part of time
- m_buffer[0] works like a flag:

  //0 = load model

  //1 = send image path

  //2 = detect

  //3 = receive

  //9 = terminate signal

Can I understand this by using threads window?

Comment: We can't understand it either without actually seeing all the relevant code. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: m_key_shmem is a string that identifies the shared memroy, s_shmem is the handle that you get when you do a lookup/create with the m_key_shmem, and you get m_buffer from mapping the the s_shmem handle. You can then use that memory, my guess is that the m_key_mutex is used to synchronize between processes that uses the shared memory.

Comment: @ChristopherPisz I know this is vague but stack overflow dowsn't let me share all the code. I think there is a limit for amount of code you put here

Comment: @TonyJ Thank you! your response was helpful. Is it possible to know who is using the handle and shared memory while debugging?

Comment: For someone who's "new to C++", the best use of their time would be to focus on learning the fundamentals of this most complicated general purpose programming language in use today, such as: scoping (local, global, dynamic), classes, inheritance, templates, and other parts of C++ that takes years of study to learn proficiently. This will produce far better results than trying to figure out how highly technical, operating system-specific system calls work, without even having a good grasp on the fundamentals of the language.

Comment: Agree with Sam. Windows API should be left alone until one doesn't feel new to the language.

Comment: @HadiGhahremanNezhad The same handle can only be created with the exact same string, so it's likely the same code(likely from another process) that's using it. I don't know anyways to find who else is using it, if there is a way you will find it on win32 MSDNdocumentation.

Comment: @HadiGhahremanNezhad Stack Overflow has a code size to description metric. The logic is large blocks of code must be one hell of a big problem and require a lot of description. Part of your job as the asker is to provide the minimum code that  exposes the bug and still runs (a [mcve]) . There is method to this madness. Crafting a MCVE A)forces you to  consider every line of code you include in it and B) drastically reduces the amount of noise concealing the bug. Often you don't get far into the MCVE before one of those two pretty much hands the bug to you, eliminating the need for the question

Comment: You should read the MSDN documentation for `CreateFileMappingA` and `MapViewOfFile`.